# How can I get my XBox 360 data off of a RROD console?

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, hard-drive

My older-style XBox finally died with the Red Ring Of Death (RROD). It has an external hard drive attached. The newer XBox 360s don't support that style of hard drive? I guess I could get another old one, but won't that just mean another RROD is around the corner? Are there ways of transferring the data with a transfer cable or something? Can I take the hard drive apart and somehow transmit it with my computer or something? Anything else I might be able to do?

Comment: Be sure it is a REAL RROD, I had one caused by my hard drive not being pushed in all the way, and another by the fans getting stuck by a cat. Another time was the power cable not being pushed all the way in, similar instance occurred with screen cable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the older hard drives are not directly compatible with the newer models. They won't just plug in.

Microsoft sells an official Xbox 360 Transfer Cable which will allow you to attach your old hard drive to a newer Xbox 360 model and move the data over. It can be purchased online from them, or a few other places.

The full instructions to do the transfer can be found at http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/set-up-transfer-cable

Comment: Are you sure this works? I'd assume the RROD means the console is essentially halted (similar to a bluescreen), so it will no longer talk to other components (like controllers or the USB cable) or do/access anything.

Comment: @Mario The hard drive disconnects from the console (in old consoles, and new ones too), and if it's truly the RROD, it has nothing to do with an error on the hard drive. The data should be fine. The transfer cable connects directly to the old hard drive, not the old Xbox, so it doesn't require the old machine to be working, just the drive.